# Error while working with List<? extends DefaultMutableTreeNodel>

Tags: java, list, jtree, extends

```
public void findClassNodesMatching(String lowerCaseSearchText, List<? extends DefaultMutableTreeNode> foundNodes) {
    findClassNodesMatching(lowerCaseSearchText, (DefaultMutableTreeNode) getRoot(), foundNodes);
}

private void findClassNodesMatching(String lowerCaseSearchText, DefaultMutableTreeNode node, List<? extends DefaultMutableTreeNode> foundNodes) {
    String nodeLabel = node.toString().toLowerCase();
    if (nodeLabel.indexOf(lowerCaseSearchText) >= 0) {
        foundNodes.add(node);
    }
}
```

**Why does this code give an error**

> The method add(capture#2-of ? extends DefaultMutableTreeNode) in the
>   type List is not
>   applicable for the arguments (DefaultMutableTreeNode)

**The error is at the line of** `foundNodes.add(node);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *add* to a list where you only know the type as a `List<? extends Something>` constraint. Imagine you could:

```
List<Banana> bananas = new ArrayList<Banana>();
// This is fine, right?
List<? extends Fruit> fruit = bananas;

// We don't want to be able to add an apple to a list of bananas!
fruit.add(new Apple());

// ... as otherwise this is no longer safe
Banana bananas = bananas.get(0);
```

It's exactly the same thing in your case - imagine you passed in some `List<SomeVerySpecificKindOfNode>`; you shouldn't be able to add *any* `DefaultMutableTreeNode` to that.

It's not clear what your context is, but just changing your code to use `List<DefaultMutableTreeNode>` in both places may well be enough to fix it. It depends on the callers.